# How to determine if a part of the text is related to food safety

Tags: nlp

I am going to analyze the takeaway comments and look for information related to food safety, but I am in a dilemma. I don't know how to judge whether it is related to food safety.
There's no solution when i google nlp and food safety.
If any idea you can provide, much thanks.

Comment: One approach would be to create a list of words which are related to food safety and filter the comments which contain at least one word of such a list.

Comment: Label a few hundred sentences - this is a text classification problem. You can use resources from fast.ai http://nlp.fast.ai/category/classification.html